# Is it a browser bug that I can't use js labeled statements with an if?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, ecmascript-6, language-lawyer, labeled-statements

Disclaimer: Yes, I know `goto` is bad, I'm interested here in the spec and implementations, not best practices.

I have this super simple [javascript example of a labeled statement](http://jsbin.com/royamov/1/edit?js,console)

```
let i = 0;
foo:
if(i < 5) {
    console.log(i);
    i +=1;
    continue foo;
}
```

As far as I can tell for the spec for [labelled statements](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-labelled-statements) and for [statements](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-statements-and-declarations) this should work!

So am I reading the spec wrong or is there a bug somewhere?

Note that usage [as shown on MDN with `for` statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) works fine

Comment: `continue` can only be used with loops. `if` isn't a loop.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[From the specification for `continue`:](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-continue-statement-static-semantics-early-errors)

> It is a Syntax Error if this production is not nested, directly or indirectly (but not crossing function boundaries), within an *IterationStatement*.

[An *IterationStatement* is defined as a `for` loop or a `case` block.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-statement-rules) An `if` block is an *IfStatement*, not an *IterationStatement*, so you cannot use `continue` inside one.

Comment: That link is specifically about statements in tail position. [The spec for continue](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-continue-statement) seems to say no such thing?

Comment: @GeorgeMauer The bit I quoted appears right below the anchor you linked, in section number 13.8.1.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-continue-statement-static-semantics-early-errors .

Comment: Oh my god, that's so weird. You *can* [do this](http://jsbin.com/royamov/2/edit?js,console)

Comment: It might be worth explicitly saying that there is no problem with the label but with `continue`.

Comment: @GeorgeMauer: Yes, because now `continue` is nested inside a `while`  loop.

Comment: yup, a pointless `while` loop that is needed *solely* to get the syntax working :) Next...see what happens if I try this with a `do...while`

Comment: @GeorgeMauer Correct. `continue` needs to be in a loop, but there is (as far as I'm aware) no check that the label you `continue` to is part of that loop…

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `continue` can only be used in a loop.

> The continue statement terminates execution of the statements in the current iteration of the current or labeled loop, and continues execution of the loop with the next iteration.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue

Comment: See, but that's a link to MDN which is an occasionally fallible digest of the spec. Looking at the spec itself - which I linked - it says that labels are followed by any statement and a statement is defined as an `if`. So how is using it here not valid?